# d3.js - Generate ticks only to max value

Tags: d3.js

How to set tick max value that will be generated (visible) on an axis ? I have multi-line chart with multiple y axis. One of line chart has max value in half of axis y. How to prevent generating ticks above this max value ? Now i'm using `.tickValues(domain);`, but this generate only min and max.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `domain` is an array of the min and max values this is expected. Try something like

```
.tickValues(d3.range(domain[0], domain[1]+1))
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v349S/) to play with

Comment: This is close to something i need. Do You have a idea to get only x values beetween min and max from `d3.range` ? Hm... counting step...

Comment: I found: `var step = (domain[1] - domain[0])/10;` to get 10 ticks ;) Thank You for `d3.range`!